# Custom Css Not Working in magento 2

Tags: css, magento2

Hello I am new to magento2 I am trying to add custom css in my project, but it is not reflecting.
I have included the file in default_head_block.xml also the current application mode is on development.
Help appreciated[image]

Comment: you should look at this post : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/108690/13859

Comment: It is about creating custom theme, what if I have to add only a css file @viCky

Comment: yes, creating the custom theme will allow you to add your css file. You do not need to add anything else or change anything else.

Comment: it worked thank you @viCky

Comment: please share how you were able to finally solve your problem. Thanks

Comment: I created a custom theme and as given in the link magento.stackexchange.com/a/108690/13859 and included the css file in blank/magento_theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml file

Comment: please put this into Your Answer and after submitting click on the tick on the left of the answer to close the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I thing need to run this command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```